# How do I find the disk in this USB 3 enclosure

Tags: external-hard-drive, fedora

I bought one of these [Nexstar dual disk docks](http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/494) and attached it to my Fedora 23 PC via eSATA.  I had one disk in it and there was no issue identifying the disk, formatting and mounting it.

I now want to add a second drive. I powered off the dock, added the drive and powered it back on. I can still see the original drive (as sdd1) but see no indication (in dmesg) of the new drive.

Am I wrong to think I can have two disks and mount them both over the same eSata connection?

FWIW, the PC has three internal hard disks as well as this external dock (it is my media server).

Comment: i'd detach the first drive (unmount, power off dock, remove drive) and put the new drive in alone, just to make sure it works through the dock.  (try both slots if necessary.)  if that works over esata, and both drives docked still doesn't, try over the USB interface.  and try the working drive in the second slot; it's always possible the dock has a busted slot.

Comment: Thanks i swapped the two disks and now the new disk is visible. The first is not. It is a brand new dock so I hadn't thought it might be bad. But...